# Stacking multiple dataframes together for different timestamp format into one timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, strptime

I have multiple data frames each  having data  varying from 1 to 1440 minute (one day).Each dataframes are alike and same columns and same length. The time column values are in `hhmm` format.
Lets say df_A has the data of 1st day, that is  `2021-05-06` It looks like this.

```
>df_A
timestamp    col1   col2.....  col80
0
1
2
.
.
.
2359
```

And the next day's data is in df_B which is also the same. The date is `2021-05-07`

```
>df_B
timestamp    col1   col2.....  col80
0
1
2
.
.
.
2359
```

How could I stack these together one under another and create one dataframe while identifying each rows with a column having values in format like `YYYYMMDD HH:mm`. Which somewhat will look like this:

```
>df
timestamp      col1    col2.....  col80
20210506 0000
20210506 0001
.
.
20210506 2359
20210507 0000
.
.
20210507 2359
```

How could I achieve this while dealing with multiple data frames at ones?

Comment: If columns name are same then you can append both df's...i.e `df1.append(df2)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas The confusion is how to fix the datetime problem.Appending is easy.But changing their datetime format and unifying them into my desired datetime format is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df_A = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 10), columns=['timestamp'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 10), columns=['timestamp'])


df_A['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-05-06 ' + 
                              df_A['timestamp'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%Y-%m-%d %H%M')

df_B['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-05-07 ' + 
                              df_A['timestamp'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%Y-%m-%d %H%M')

df_final = pd.concat([df_A, df_B])

df_final
```

```
    timestamp   date
0   0   2021-05-06 00:00:00
1   1   2021-05-06 00:01:00
2   2   2021-05-06 00:02:00
3   3   2021-05-06 00:03:00
4   4   2021-05-06 00:04:00
5   5   2021-05-06 00:05:00
6   6   2021-05-06 00:06:00
7   7   2021-05-06 00:07:00
8   8   2021-05-06 00:08:00
9   9   2021-05-06 00:09:00
0   0   2021-05-07 00:00:00
1   1   2021-05-07 00:01:00
2   2   2021-05-07 00:02:00
3   3   2021-05-07 00:03:00
4   4   2021-05-07 00:04:00
5   5   2021-05-07 00:05:00
6   6   2021-05-07 00:06:00
7   7   2021-05-07 00:07:00
8   8   2021-05-07 00:08:00
9   9   2021-05-07 00:09:00
```

Comment: I am facing this error ``` ValueError: time data '2021-03-210001' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H%M' (match)```. Not sure why

Comment: did u copy correctly there is a space between `%Y-%m-%d` and `%Y-%m-%d`  like `'2021-03-21 0001'` for the format `%Y-%m-%d %H%M`? And why r u facing this error? What r u trying to do? I already put the space `'2021-05-06 '+...` see the space after 06

Comment: I apologise, it works perfectly. I did some mistake in the space. Thanks a ton